# Trouble uploading a sql file to mysql using shell terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql

I'm trying to upload a sql file to mysql on AWS using my shell terminal. I can login fine and everything works great. I used FTP to  transfer a sql file to my html folder and I'm trying to import it to an already existing mysql database using the following command:

```
sudo mysql -u ubuntu -p dbasename < /var/www/html/nameoffile.sql
```

But when I run this command I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw and please use google before posting a question. Thank you.

Comment: @Raja yes, that worked thank you. I did look on Google first but I guess I didn't know what I was looking for exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got solved your issue , I just googled your error code. Please close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @Raja answer above. It's a simple matter of remembering to use the MySQL USER and not the OS user for the operation (in my case). Although the link given has many other things to consider as well if you're having this problem.

Raja if you want to add an answer as well I'll change mine to yours, or if it's desired to just delete this altogether I get that too.